# "If I had had money, I [would give/could give/would have given] you..."

Tags: conditionals

> I wish I had had money. If I had had money...

1. I would have given you...
2. I would give you...
3. I could give you...

Which one is correct? Please let me know.

Comment: Gave an answer but is it just me or there are really a lot of topics about would and conditionals in general?

Comment: Hello, Maahi Singh. The reason your question received a downvote, I suspect, is that you don't seem to have done anything more than copy out a quiz question and ask for the right answer to it. At this site we expect questioners to explain what difficulty they are having with a particular issue of English language and usage. In the case of a multiple-choice question, that would involve providing your analysis of the question, identifying the answer that you think is most plausible, and saying why you prefer it. Essentially, we like to see some effort on the questioner's part.

Comment: I mean can we use 'If I had had money I would give you' I think It's wrong because we are talking  about the past and I would give you it's present form so according to grammar It should be like this " If I had had money. I would have given you " I think that's why I was bit confused

Answer (score 1):

First option. You are talking about 'unreal past'.

If I had had money, I would have given it to you. (I didn't have, so I didn't give you).

If I had known, I would have visited you. (I didn't know, so I didn't visit you).

Answer (score 1):

They might all be correct. The condition is an *unreal past*, as Grizzly points out. However, there's nothing to stop actions from being conditional on unreal pasts - the condition simply stays unfulfilled.

Examples following your three points:

1. If he had had money, he would have given you some of it. (*He didn't have it, so he didn't share it.*)
2. If he had had money, he would give you a present. (*He didn't have it then, and is now using that as an excuse for him not being generous.*)
3. If he had had money, he could give you advice on how he got it. (*He didn't have it then, so he has no advice now to impart on this subject.*)

Comment: I also sometimes heard or read the turn, "If I 'would have had' [money], I would have [given you]..." https://www.google.fr/search?q=total+recall&biw=1024&bih=672&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiNm5eFrf_KAhXDMBoKHb4iCh8Q_AUIBygA&dpr=2#q=%22if+i+would+have+had+money%22 I guess this usage is chiefly colloquial and considered nonstandard.